# Change duration of canvas animation with Request Animation Frame

Tags: animation, canvas, requestanimationframe

I'm trying to animate a circle that will draw itself similar to a progress bar. I'm intending to use it on a carousel to track when the next slide is coming up. The problem I'm having is I don't know how to change the duration of the animation. I tried adjusting the framerate, and it works but the animation gets really choppy. setInterval kind of works but it displays the entire circle rather than just a portion of it like I'm intending, so I can't time things properly. I need to be able to control the speed of the animation, slowing it down without it being stuttery. The code I'm working on is below.

```
<script>    
    (function() {
        var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || 
                                    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                                    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
                                    window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
                                    window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
    })();
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
        var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
        var radius = 90;
        var endPercent = 85;
        var curPerc = 0;
        var circ = -Math.PI;
        var quart = -(Math.PI * 2) + 1;

        function animate(current) {
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, -(quart), ((circ) * current) - quart, true);
            context.lineWidth = 3;
            context.strokeStyle = '#000';
            context.stroke();
            curPerc++;
            if (curPerc < endPercent) {
                requestAnimationFrame(function () {
                animate(curPerc / 100)
                });
            }
        }

     animate();
</script>
```

Comment: Here is a [good article](https://www.viget.com/articles/time-based-animation) and [github gist](https://gist.github.com/greypants/3739036) accompanying it, on time-based canvas animations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`requestAnimationFrame` does pass an high resolution timestamp in the callback argument. So you could use it to determine where you are in your current animation, and use this delta time to set your positions variables instead of `curPerc++`.

Here is a naive implementation.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = 90;
var endPercent = 85;
var quart = -(Math.PI * 2) + 1;
var startTime = null;
var duration = null;

function animate(time) {

  if (!startTime) {
    startTime = time;
  }

  var delta = Math.min(1, (time - startTime) / duration);
  var curPerc = ((-2 * Math.PI) / 100) * (endPercent * delta);

  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, -quart, curPerc - quart, true);
  context.stroke();

  if (delta < 1) {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  } else {
    startTime = null;
    slider.disabled = false;
  }
}

var startAnim = function() {
  context.lineWidth = 3;
  context.strokeStyle = '#000';

  slider.disabled = true;
  duration = +slider.value;
  l.textContent = duration + 'ms';
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
};
slider.onchange = startAnim;
startAnim();
```

```html
<p>use the slider to update the animation's duration</p>
<input type="range" min="250" max="9000" value="2000"id="slider" />
<label id="l"></label><br>
<canvas id="myCanvas" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: @markE, you're right edited. Usually I even add a "draw last frame" call in the `if(delta>=1)` that I do place on top of my anim function. Just too lazy to do it properly here with OP's structure.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I searched through so many things and couldn't find the right answer.